# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Push notifications error: "Error while trying to retrieve device token from the mobile operating system"

Tags: android, android-emulator, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to add push notifications to my app but I can't get [the sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/PushNotificationsProject.zip) to work.

This is what I did:

- Downloaded sample project
- Opened in Worklight 5.0.6
- Registered project id and API key at Google
- Entered id and key in application-descriptor.xml like so:

  *<pushSender key="XXX senderId="YYY"/>*
- Deployed adapter
- Built the app ("Build all and deploy", Android SDK API 18, Google API 18)
- Checked worklight console's Push Notifications tab (app and adapter are listed there) and the push notification tab [image: http://s14.directupload.net/images/131022/nex9fth5.png]
- Started the app in android emulator (4.3)
- In sample app, logged in with user "spyro", password "test"
- Got an error:

> Failed registering for push notifications. The application will not
>   be able to receive notifications

LogCat gives me the following messages:

> 10-22 06:07:11.178: E/SQLiteLog(2600): (14) cannot open file at line
>   30191 of [00bb9c9ce4] 10-22 06:07:11.178: E/SQLiteLog(2600): (14)
>   os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) -  10-22
>   06:10:58.392: W/WLDroidGap(2600): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not
>   registered: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push$1@b419ff38 10-22
>   06:10:58.402: W/WLDroidGap(2600): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not
>   registered: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push$3@b41a0458 10-22
>   06:10:58.442: E/PushApplication(2600): Error while trying to retrieve
>   device token from the mobile operating system.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following will resolve your problem, which is setting up push notifications in the **Android Emulator**; to have push notifications in the emulator it is required to install from the Android SDK Manager some support libraries.

1. First, make sure that you have followed all steps described in the [Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf), specifically slides 41 and 47.
2. Follow the steps described in the answer to this SO question:

   - [IBM Worklight - Push Notifications feature does not work in Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021158/ibm-worklight-push-notifications-feature-does-not-work-in-android-emulator) -- you **must** install the [Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) (available in the Extras category)

[image]

---

In your updated question you do not mention whether you've installed the push notifications feature library, and you must install it.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work either.
- I've already registered a project-ID and device-key at Google. Also put them in application-descriptor.xml like show above.
- I downloaded Google APIs (18) and rebuilt the project. Same error. :(

Comment: Then I do not know how exactly you set up your project, the instructions are sound and valid. Edit your **question** with exactly what you've done. Elaborate.

Comment: As seen in your updated question, you did not install the  Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library (available in the Extras category).

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I must have overseen this because this library is marked as deprecated in the SDK manager. I downloaded the lib, rebuilt the project, redeployed the adapter, restarted the AVD but I got still the same error.

Comment: It is not deprecated... I added a screen shot to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, in my SDK manager it's clearly marked as deprecated: http://s14.directupload.net/images/131022/d3hk6wa7.png

Comment: Then you need to consult with the Android documentation; if Google removed push notifications support from their Emulators, you will need to test with an actual device.

Comment: I read that Google is switching from their Messaging library to Play Services. Be sure to install that as well.