# IBM Worklight - Sent push notification to Android are not arriving

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I've downloaded the push notifications project from "Woklight getting started" and I've installed it in my device with the proper API key and senderId. I've deployed the adapter and it's working fine. 
Now I'm trying to do the test of sending push notifications to the device.

To log in the application I can use arbitrary values, am I right? 
Like Username="Santaclaus" and Password="cheese".

Then to invoke the adapter procedure by right-clicking the adapter > invoke procedure > specify username and message, in the username I will put "Santaclaus" and in the message "Blabla bla bla", am I correct?

The problem is that when I press the Run button, the Invocation Result of procedure: 'submitNotification' from the Worklight Server:

```
    {
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "result": "Notification sent to user :: Santaclaus"
}
```

and the console shows this error:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.010 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://L3CDH3K.corp.capgemini.com:10080/PushNotifications/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application PushNotifications has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.030 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://L3CDH3K.corp.capgemini.com:10080/PushNotifications/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application PushNotifications started in 3.362 seconds.
[WARNING ] FWLSE0029W: Registration of application PushNotifications-android-1.0 to mediator occured more than once. [project PushNotifications]
[WARNING ] FWLSE0029W: Registration of application PushNotifications-android-1.0 to mediator occured more than once. [project PushNotifications]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0094E: Error while attempting to invoke GCM service (for sender key starting with 'AIzaSyBb'), sending will not resume until server is restarted or application re-deployed [project PushNotifications]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0093E: Failed to invoke Google GCM push service. [project PushNotifications]
GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Authentication has failed for sender key starting with 'AIzaSyBb')
[WARNING ] Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
```

and the LogCat shows:

```
01-02 10:15:27.873: D/PushNotifications(7609): wlclient init started
01-02 10:15:27.883: D/PushNotifications(7609): Read cookies: null
01-02 10:15:27.883: D/PushNotifications(7609): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
01-02 10:15:27.933: W/PushNotifications(7609): Your application is using the WL.OptionsMenu API. Note that, if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
01-02 10:15:27.943: D/PushNotifications(7609): addDeviceIDHeader deviceIDSuccessCallback
01-02 10:15:27.963: D/PushNotifications(7609): connectOnStartup
01-02 10:15:27.973: D/PushNotifications(7609): connectOnStartup isCertificateExists:  false
01-02 10:15:28.473: D/PushNotifications(7609): Request [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init]
01-02 10:15:28.563: D/CordovaActivity(7609): onMessage(spinner,stop)
01-02 10:15:30.983: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7609): Ignore this event
01-02 10:15:31.083: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 448K, 8% free 8302K/8968K, paused 3ms+9ms, total 54ms
01-02 10:15:31.113: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7609): Ignore this event
01-02 10:15:32.803: D/dalvikvm(490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1668K, 18% free 15196K/18376K, paused 2ms+10ms, total 91ms
01-02 10:15:32.883: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 8% free 8280K/8968K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 29ms
01-02 10:15:37.473: D/dalvikvm(7544): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 4% free 8393K/8700K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
01-02 10:15:37.513: D/Finsky(7544): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
01-02 10:15:38.883: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7609): Ignore this event
01-02 10:15:38.923: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7609): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-02 10:15:38.923: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7609): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-02 10:15:39.003: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7609): Ignore this event
01-02 10:15:40.023: I/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads](2538): CommManager checkManifestFile started
01-02 10:15:40.023: W/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads](2538): [OPTIONAL] Could not find the com.getjar.sdk.rewards.GetJarReceiver defined inside AndroidManifest.xml. It is required if there is no other implementation of Google Play billing.
01-02 10:15:40.053: I/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads](2538): AuthFlow: ensureAuthInternal() state:STARTING
01-02 10:15:40.053: I/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads](2538): AuthFlow: ensureAuthInternal() [running auth-flow]
01-02 10:15:40.053: I/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads](2538): AuthFlow: ensureAuthInternal() finishing with state:EXPIRY_CHECKING
01-02 10:15:40.133: D/dalvikvm(2538): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5953K, 20% free 25539K/31648K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 72ms
01-02 10:15:40.133: D/dalvikvm(2538): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
01-02 10:15:44.163: D/PushNotifications(7609): Request [login]
01-02 10:15:44.243: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7609): Ignore this event
01-02 10:15:44.373: D/PushNotifications(7609): Request [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init]
01-02 10:15:48.043: D/dalvikvm(7609): GC_CONCURRENT freed 336K, 7% free 8328K/8864K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 32ms
01-02 10:15:49.433: D/PushNotifications(7609): Request [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init]
01-02 10:15:49.463: W/InputMethodManagerService(490): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4186d4c0 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41af16b8
01-02 10:15:49.723: D/PushNotifications(7609): Clearing notification subscriptions.
01-02 10:15:49.723: D/PushNotifications(7609): Updating notification subscriptions.
01-02 10:15:49.723: D/WLDroidGap(7609): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
01-02 10:15:49.723: D/WLDroidGap(7609): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
01-02 10:15:49.733: V/GCMRegistrar(7609): Registering receiver
01-02 10:15:49.733: D/GCMRegistrar(7609): resetting backoff for com.PushNotifications
01-02 10:15:49.753: V/GCMRegistrar(7609): Registering app com.PushNotifications of senders 515493207294
01-02 10:15:49.753: W/PluginManager(7609): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Push.subscribe blocked the main thread for 24ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
01-02 10:15:49.763: D/PushNotifications(7609): response [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init] success: /*-secure-
01-02 10:15:49.763: D/PushNotifications(7609): {"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"PushAppRealm":{"userId":"Santaclaus","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"Santaclaus"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"35rkplsu96msjk6hichq990k2h","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"35rkplsu96msjk6hichq990k2h"},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"05282bf4-9fe4-3c40-8280-3e627db3fe5c","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@eb49d"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"05282bf4-9fe4-3c40-8280-3e627db3fe5c"}},"userPrefs":{},"notificationSubscriptionState":{"eventSources":[{"eventSource":"PushEventSource","alias":"myPush","adapter":"PushAdapter"}],"token":"APA91bFg1hMAQcCZnLHRQ5qIZu5HdkcWpt0p99cftqXD4YrrxD8W-F5r7x3DYRGv-hY0jFTvtg5Yg9Uo1o_EjJFxkoyLUKGxNiRzmh-md9-FwCQ2gfSvTVFT1Vt6J9UigpwdWFCblB-dBBYv4U9Z2S3Vi5gvBFr9WPUwDQGR2Ez5GfQQiYj3x1k"},"gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{"updateUnpackedSize":1187754,"availableSkins":["default"],"checksum":796238133,"updateSize":385169},"ENVIRONMENT":"android"},"userInfo":{"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"PushAppRealm":{"userId":"Santaclaus","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"Santaclaus"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"35rkplsu96msjk6hichq990k2h","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"35rkplsu96msjk6hichq990k2h"},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"05282bf4-9fe4-3c40-8280-3e627db3fe5c","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@eb49d"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"05282bf4-9fe4-3c40-8280-3e627db3fe5c"},"myserver":{"userId":"Santaclaus","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"Santaclaus"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null}}}*/
01-02 10:15:49.763: D/PushNotifications(7609): wlclient connect success
01-02 10:15:49.773: D/PushNotifications(7609): before: app init onSuccess
01-02 10:15:49.783: D/PushNotifications(7609): after: app init onSuccess
01-02 10:15:49.783: D/PushNotifications(7609): added onPause event handler 
01-02 10:15:49.783: D/PushNotifications(7609): wlclient init success
01-02 10:15:49.913: D/dalvikvm(929): GC_CONCURRENT freed 408K, 8% free 8984K/9664K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 25ms
01-02 10:15:49.993: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(7609): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-02 10:15:49.993: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(7609): GCM IntentService class: com.PushNotifications.GCMIntentService
01-02 10:15:49.993: V/GCMBaseIntentService(7609): Acquiring wakelock
01-02 10:15:50.003: V/GCMBaseIntentService(7609): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-515493207294-1
01-02 10:15:50.003: D/GCMBaseIntentService(7609): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bFg1hMAQcCZnLHRQ5qIZu5HdkcWpt0p99cftqXD4YrrxD8W-F5r7x3DYRGv-hY0jFTvtg5Yg9Uo1o_EjJFxkoyLUKGxNiRzmh-md9-FwCQ2gfSvTVFT1Vt6J9UigpwdWFCblB-dBBYv4U9Z2S3Vi5gvBFr9WPUwDQGR2Ez5GfQQiYj3x1k, error = null, unregistered = null
01-02 10:15:50.003: D/GCMRegistrar(7609): resetting backoff for com.PushNotifications
01-02 10:15:50.003: V/GCMRegistrar(7609): Saving regId on app version 1
01-02 10:15:50.023: D/WLDroidGap(7609): WLGCMIntentService: Registered at the GCM server with registration id APA91bFg1hMAQcCZnLHRQ5qIZu5HdkcWpt0p99cftqXD4YrrxD8W-F5r7x3DYRGv-hY0jFTvtg5Yg9Uo1o_EjJFxkoyLUKGxNiRzmh-md9-FwCQ2gfSvTVFT1Vt6J9UigpwdWFCblB-dBBYv4U9Z2S3Vi5gvBFr9WPUwDQGR2Ez5GfQQiYj3x1k
01-02 10:15:50.023: V/GCMBaseIntentService(7609): Releasing wakelock
01-02 10:15:50.943: W/InputMethodManagerService(490): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@419c5618 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41af16b8
01-02 10:15:52.613: D/PushNotifications(7609): Request [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/notifications]
01-02 10:15:52.623: D/WLDroidGap(7609): Push.dispatch(): method=WL.Client.Push.__onmessage
01-02 10:15:52.793: D/PushNotifications(7609): response [http://192.168.16.128:10080/PushNotifications/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/notifications] success: /*-secure-
01-02 10:15:52.793: D/PushNotifications(7609): {"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
01-02 10:15:55.593: W/InputMethodManagerService(490): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41b721e8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41af16b8
```

This is the android element from application-descriptor.xml file:

```
 <android securityTest="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="true"/>
        <pushSender key="AIzaSyBb08MeW5jlh9bDSlpqHsgGgknT6QHiWn4" senderId="515493207294"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the actual public signing key of the certificate used to sign the APK, available by using the 'Extract public signing key' wizard.</publicSigningKey>
        </security>
 </android>
```

I've created a browser key from Google Cloud Console. I've created an android key in first place, I don't know which should I use. In this case I used the browser key specifying the referers as follows:

```
0E:30:5F:3A:A0:D9:A5:41:EF:FB:08:1B:7A:AC:0B:92:E1:C7:E8:33;com.PushNotifications
```

The device OS version is android 4.2.1
I'm using the last version available of Worklight Developer Edition.
Have you any idea how to make it works?

Thanks.

Comment: After you login in the app, did you click on the subscribe button? What do you see in LogCat? Any errors? anything?

Comment: Yes, I clicked on the subscribe button and a dialog said `Success`. The invoke procedure result says Invocation Result of procedure: 'submitNotification' from the Worklight Server: {
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "result": "Notification sent to user :: Santaclaus"
} and the LogCat does not show a thing.

Comment: Did you send the notification to the same user you've logged with? Also you must get your LogCat to work. There are always logs.

Comment: Yes, I sent to the same user. What log is supposed to appear in LogCat when I send the notification? My LogCat doesn't show anything.

Comment: Get your LogCat working. When you see there something, paste the log in the question: https://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+does+not+show+anything

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. What is strange is that the LogCat does not work when I start up this application (PushNotifications) in the device, but when I start up another application also installed from the worklight the LogCat works fine.

Comment: I've already put the LogCat working and I edited my question with the log error.

Comment: Edit the question with 1) the FULL log from LogCat, don't put pieces from it. 2) Add the device OS version. 3) Add the Worklight version. 4) Add the ANDROID element from application-descriptor.xml; maybe you've used incorrect GCM Key and senderID values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the set-up instructions as provided here: [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Android notification does not reach either device or emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551069/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-android-notification-does-not-reach-either-device-or-emu)

- The emulator instructions are not relevant in your case
- When creating the **browser key**, simply do `Create New Key > Browser Key > Create`.
- Do **not** edit it afterwards, i.e. do not add anything in the "Accept requests..." section. In your question you mention that you do this - undo it.

Comment: See page #44 in the training module, verify all ports are open. Also delete the app from the device, re-build and deploy, re-run. http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf

Comment: You are saying to create a browser key instead of a android key. But in ´Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites) One URL or pattern per line. Example: *.example.com/*´ I don't know what to insert in this case. If I choose android key, it's prompt SHA1 fingerprint and the package name, made more sense for me. To go to Browser key I enter in project and select APIs & auth > Credentials > Public API access > Create new key, right?

Comment: Create just a Browser Key, not Android Key, Browser Key, copy it and put as the GCM Key in application-descriptor.xml. "Accept requests..." should remain empty.

Comment: I still have a problem :( A push notification just appear on the device the first time I sent it. If I try to send another one, it doesn't appear on the device. To work again I have to delete the project from the eclipse, import it, and run it again. This is not normal, is it?

Comment: Delete the project from Eclipse?! What does that have to do with receiving a notification in the Device? No... this is not normal and you also don't need to do that at all. There is only 1 notification displayed in the notification bar in Android, if another notification is incoming, it replaces the existing notification in the notification, so send 2 notifications with different text and make sure that you get both.

Comment: What notification bar? I would like to see the message in the notification bar, but just appear alerts with code and my message inside, and as I said only the first time I sent a notification from the Invoke Worklight Procedure. I know that is stupid to delete the project from eclipse but it worked again (and again just one time) after I delete it and import it again.

Comment: Okay, I just don't understand you at all. I see you are from Cap Gemini; email me on Monday next week and we'll talk about it via email or phone. Are you working on a UniCredit application?

Comment: No, I'm just making a prototype and exploring worklight push notifications. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I discovered the problem. The problem is that when I tried to send the second notification I just replaced the message inside quotes. When I erased everything inside the Parameters textbox and wrote again the username and message, it worked fine! Sorry for the mess and thank you for your patience.