# Enabling push notifications on Android using Worklight

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having some issues getting push notifications to work on Android.  I have added a pushSender to the android section of the application-descriptor.xml with the key that was generated (I've removed our key values).

```
<android version="1.0.5">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <pushSender key="our key" senderId="our sender"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="true"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="true" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>our key</publicSigningKey>
    </security>
</android>
```

Every time I start the app, I get the message "Failed registering for push notifications. The application will not be able to receive notifications.

I thought for a little while that it may be because I was testing on our internal network and it needed access to the outside world, but even when it could get to the world, I still received the message. I've tried adding the securityTest parameter to the android tag, but it did not make any difference.

In the authenticationconfig.xml file, I've added a mobile security test to the security tests section:

```
    <mobileSecurityTest name="PushApp-securityTest">
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
        <testUser realm="PushAppRealm"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

I have the realm set up like this:

```
    <realm name="PushAppRealm" loginModule="PushAppLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.PersistentCookieAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>
```

And the login module is like this:

```
    <loginModule name="PushAppLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
```

I'm really lost as to why it is failing to register. We're running Worklight 5.0.6.2.

Comment: See my setup given in the following question. While it was tested with 6.2, it is the same for 5.0.6.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818382/ibm-worklight-android-push-notification-sent-but-not-received/24829596#24829596

Comment: @idan-adar For this to work, do you have to use some sort of actual login (i.e. entering a user id/password)? We want to allow the app to receive push notifications without them logging in, and I thought that the PersistenCookieAuthenticator would allow that. I've been through the process of setting up the GCM key. I did not realize we needed to use a browser key and not a server key, but even with the browser key, I still get the failed to register message.

Comment: You could explicitly register the device, but a good citizen(app) would check with the user first. ...

Comment: We're not planning to just blindly set up a user for push notifications. We're going to check to see if they are registered and give them a pop-up to ask if they'd like to receive the notifications. Could there be an issue with the key I'm entering? I was under the impression that the PersistentCookieAuthenticator would create a device type ID to be the "user" to register, so that an explicit logon would not be required. I just wonder about the key, as if I comment out the pushSender from the app descriptor but do not remove any of the code for push notifications, the app starts fine.

Comment: Are you using the right value for the senderID ? I was receiving the same error message and just found that I was using the "Project ID" instead of the "Project Number". You need to use the "Project Number" in the senderID field.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> For this to work, do you have to use some sort of actual login (i.e.
>   entering a user id/password)?

If you are using Event source-based notifications, then yes - a login is required.
You can read an explanation here: [receive GCM push without WLClient::connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678122/receive-gcm-push-without-wlclientconnect)

It sounds like for this particular need of yours, you could use either Broadcast or Tag-based notifications. You can read more about these types in [this user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html). The topic also provides example implementations to follow-up with.