# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Is there any settings we have to do on worklight server, in order to enable push notification on android?

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded, sample PushNotification from IBM website, and while running the application on android ICS 4.0, I get this error:

> Can't Subscribe, notification token not updated on the server

- I have updated application-descriptor.xml with my API Key and Sender ID
- This is my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tf3c9nmp6baivh/PushNotifications.rar

Comment: If you are using Proxy-connection for internet this wont work

Comment: I am not using proxy connection for internet.

Comment: Add the full log from LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no special setting in Worklight Server, just correct setup in the application-level (or emulator).

You mention that you use 5.0.6.1, but your `application-descriptor.xml` is a mixture of 6.1.0 and 5.0.6.1...

If you intend on using 5.0.6.1, then use the correct sample project.
Use the [Push Notifications project from here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/wl_gs_all_samples.zip).

Next, I have tested your project. And it is working for me OK (after fixing the application-descriptor.xml file).
See screen shot at the bottom.

I am guessing that you are simply mis-configuring something else...
Double-check the steps you have done by following the instructions in the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551069/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-android-notification-does-not-reach-either-device-or-emu).

[image]

Comment: Error is in Android emulator.

Comment: So yeah, follow the instructions in the linked questions step-by-step. Should then work.

Comment: Is it compulsory to have worklight server for Push Notification? I just have worklight studio.

Comment: Worklight Studio Developer Edition contains a built-in Worklight Server.

Comment: I follow the steps shown in above example, and tested the app on android 4.1.2, but still showing same error.

Comment: Well, if you want you can upload your Worklight project (export it from Eclipse) to Dropbox and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have uploaded my project in rar file to dropbox. Here its URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tf3c9nmp6baivh/PushNotifications.rar

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq, this sample is all-wrong. What is the full download location you've used? Its application-descriptor.xml is not up to date at all. Make sure you use Worklight 6.1 and use this sample: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/PushNotificationsProject.zip - try again

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Comment: I am using Worklight 5.0.6.1

Comment: Okay. Let me test with 5.0.6.x

Comment: Use the push sample project from this zip file: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/wl_gs_all_samples.zip

Comment: I am bit confused about it, I have to point it to my worklight server or gcm server?

Comment: In application-descriptor.xml you use the WorklightServerRootURL element to point the app to the Worklight Server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replay and for giving me your precise time, I have successfully able to run the given sample in my development environment.