# Worklight Flight Ticket Sample App, push notification issues

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed the Worklight Flight Ticket Sample App in Eclipse and Worklight 6.1.from http://ibm.co/1oJaz71

I have followed your instructions on this forum http://bit.ly/1kOPveN to create a senderID and API key on the Google Developer site: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

I have inserted the senderID and API key in the application-descriptor.xml file as follows: (I have replaced the actual values with "..." for the purpose of this post).

```
<android version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <pushSender key="......." senderId="....."/>        
    <security>            
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, 
          mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the public key of the certificate with
            which you sign the APK. For details see the Worklight Developer's Reference Guide.  
        </publicSigningKey>            
    </security>
</android>
```

Please note: I have not inserted my , since I am running in the emulator and haven't seen any requirement in the documentation to do so.

Now when I run the app in the emulator it comes up and and I get the following pop-up:

Failed registering for push notifications
  The application will not be able to receive notifications.
  Your device does not support GCM. Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf.
  If you are using an android emulator make sure it has Google APIs (Google Inc).

Now, in the Android SDK manager I have already installed Google APIs.

Also, when I click on the OK button in the popup window, I soon get a second popup which says:

```
 Confirm. Do you allow Flight Ticket to send notification to you Cancel/OK.
```

I click OK, and then again soon the first popup window shows up:

Failed registering for push notifications
  The application will not be able to receive notifications.
  Your device does not support GCM. Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf.
  If you are using an android emulator make sure it has Google APIs (Google Inc).

How do you suggest that I debug this?

I am appending part of the error log:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.7.0_45-b18 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ADMINIB-3IAG8DV:10080/module_60_4_FlightTicket/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application module_60_4_FlightTicket started in 7.968 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ADMINIB-3IAG8DV:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.076 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]FTAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "body": {
            "content": "oneWay=true&fromDate=1392526800000&toAirport=HKG&fromAirport=LHR&returnDate=1392526800000",
            "contentType": "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
         },
         "headers": {
            "HOST": "localhost"
         },
         "method": "POST",
         "path": "\/flightticket\/service\/flights\/queryflights",
         "returnedContentType": "json"
      }
   ]
}
Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refusedjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:176)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:160)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:135)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:124)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:484)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$4.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:387)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:384)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:443)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:427)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_10(/integration.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5._c_FlightsREST_getTripFlights_6(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js:64)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5.call(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5.call(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:239)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 56 more

                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]FTAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "body": {
            "content": "oneWay=true&fromDate=1392526800000&toAirport=HKG&fromAirport=LHR&returnDate=1392526800000",
            "contentType": "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
         },
         "headers": {
            "HOST": "localhost"
         },
         "method": "POST",
         "path": "\/flightticket\/service\/flights\/queryflights",
         "returnedContentType": "json"
      }
   ]
}
Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refusedjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:176)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:160)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:135)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:124)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:484)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$4.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:387)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:384)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:443)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:427)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_10(/integration.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5._c_FlightsREST_getTripFlights_6(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js:64)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5.call(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5Ceclipsekepler_5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket_5Cadapters_5CFTAdapter_FTAdapter_impl_js_5.call(C%3A%5Ceclipsekepler%5Cmodule_60_4_FlightTicket%5Cadapters%5CFTAdapter/FTAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:239)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: It seems to me that the key data points in making this sample app work are:

Comment: The key points in making this sample app work in Worklight Developer Edition 6.1 are: 1) Creating a project in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html and getting your GCM sender ID and API Key as well as setting Google Cloud Messaging for Android to ON. And 2) inserting a <pushSender key="...." senderId="...."> with the values you got from the Google site in the application-descriptor.xml file in your app in Eclipse. But is that all, because I consistently get the error message "Failed registering for push notifications..." when running the sample in the Android emulator.

Comment: PS, the error log shows the following message:Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android emulator you need choose the "Google APIs" enabled one which support push notification feature. When you setup your AVD, you need to choose that API Level.

You can refer to [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Android notification does not reach either device or emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551069/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-android-notification-does-not-reach-either-device-or-emu) for more details.